# [PostgreSQL]How to make an upsert function that takes as input a query, returned by another function

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql, upsert

So I have a set of functions that perform calculation and return a table of result (multiple rows and columns).
I want to pass this result into an upsert function I made that will store rows that will be updated into a history table, then upsert the content of the input table in target table.
I know I could do this with triggers but in this case it is not an option.

Example
Setup table and data :

```
CREATE TABLE target (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    fk1 int4 NULL,
    from_dt timestamptz NOT NULL,
    to_dt timestamptz NULL,
    value text NULL,
    version int4,
    CONSTRAINT target_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT target_un UNIQUE (fk1, from_dt)
);
```

```
INSERT INTO target (fk1,from_dt,to_dt,value,"version") VALUES (14,'2023-01-01','2023-01-02','3.14',1);
INSERT INTO target (fk1,from_dt,to_dt,value,"version") VALUES (57,'2023-01-01','2023-01-02','20',1);
```

```
CREATE TABLE target_h (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    fk1 int4 NULL,
    from_dt timestamptz NOT NULL,
    to_dt timestamptz NULL,
    value text NULL,
    version int4,
    CONSTRAINT target_h_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT target_h_un UNIQUE (fk1, from_dt, version)
);
```

And I have a set of function that will calculate batches of rows to be inserted in this target table.
For the example i'll just get the record of target and change version

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc()
    RETURNS TABLE (
        fk1 int4,
        from_dt timestamptz,
        to_dt timestamptz,
        value text,
        version int4
    )
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $function$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY 
        select 
        t.fk1,
        t.from_dt,
        t.to_dt,
        t.value,
        t.version +1
        from target t;
END;
$function$
;
```

This function returns a table with the 2 records but changes their version.
Now I want the result of this query to be an input for my upsert function that will :

1.Identify records that will be updated in target

2.Copy these records into target_h

3.Insert input records into target with an on conflict update statement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION values_upsert(
    vals target[] 
)
    RETURNS VOID
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
DECLARE
    vals_h target[];
    v_from_dt timestamptz;
begin
    -- Get v_from_dt value (all dates in from_dt column are always equal)
    select max(from_dt) into v_from_dt from unnest(vals);
    -- Check if the conflict (update) occurs
    select ARRAY[t] into vals_h from target t
    where t.from_dt =v_from_dt and t.fk1 in (select fk1 from unnest(vals) as v where v.version!=1)
    FOR UPDATE;

    -- Insert the old values into the history table
    IF array_length(vals_h,1) IS NOT NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO target_h (fk1,from_dt,to_dt,value,"version")
        select vh.fk1, vh.from_dt, vh.to_dt, vh.value, vh.version
        from unnest(vals_h) AS vh;
    END IF;
   
    -- Perform the upsert operation
    INSERT INTO target (fk1,from_dt,to_dt,value,"version")
    select v.fk1, v.from_dt, v.to_dt, v.value, v.version 
    from unnest(vals) AS v
    ON CONFLICT (fk1,from_dt) DO UPDATE
    set
    to_dt = excluded.to_dt,
    value = excluded.value,
    version = excluded.version
    ;
END;
$$;
```

When trying to use upsert value :
with inputV as (
select * from calc()
)
select values_upsert(array_agg(inputV.*)) from inputV;

I get an error :

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function values_upsert(record[]) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 51
```

I understand this is a conflict between the type of the input I'm passing and the type of the parameter I declared in the function, but I don't know where to go from there.
I reckon I should probably use set of record variable instead, but I was unsuccessful so far.

If it succeds I expect to have 2 records in table target_h that will be both at version=1 and 2 records in table target that will be version = 2.

For context : target scenario is that I use this function to upsert up to 1 million records per day.

Comment: Try `values_upsert(array_agg(inputV))` or `values_upsert(array_agg(inputV::target))`. I'd also declare `calc` to `RETURN SETOF target`

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, Your second suggestion seems to be a step in the right direction, however, since I do not have the id column (first one) returned from calc as it is an auto-increment, I think I need to specify a subset of column rather than just casting to the table and I'm also not sure how to do that.